# LWC - Using NavigationMixin.Navigate doesn't work in some contexts. I require it to work within a LightningModal component

Tags: lightning-web-components, navigationmixin.navigate, lightning-modal

I have a custom component **cmpLookup** that has a lightning input. Upon typing a text into this input, records with a matching name are shown. Upon clicking any of the suggestions, user is redirected to the record detail.

[image]

I add cmpLookup as a child within **cmpA**, which is embedded into the Home flexipage. **Clicking one of the suggestions here will correctly redirect the user to the record detail.**

I also add cmpLookup as a child within **cmpModal**, a LightningModal component which is shown on the same Home flexipage when clicking a button (another lwc).
**When clicking one of the suggestions in this case, nothing happens.**

I wrap the Navigate call in a try/catch, but no error is shown.

Here's the specific Navigate call:

```
onSelect(event) {
    try {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: event.currentTarget.dataset.id,
                objectApiName: 'Account',
                actionName: 'view'
            },
        });
    } catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```